# Setting Date Field ValidationRule gives Error 3309 "Property value is too big."

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have an Access Database with two large tables, each with many date fields.  Each Date field has its individual valid dates from some day in the past through today.  So at start-up, I have used the following VBA code for years

```
fld.ValidationRule = "(>= #" & Strings.Format(fldFirstDate, "Short Date") & "# AND " & _
                     " <= #" & Strings.Format(DateTime.Date, "Short Date") & "#) OR=0 or IS NULL"
fld.ValidationText = "Enter a valid date between " & Strings.Format(fldFirstDate, "Short Date") & " and now."
```

and it has worked fine.  fldFirstDate is a date value which has been looked up in another table.

Recently, having added several more date fields to one large table, each with its own first valid date.  And I started to get the 3309 error.

So I simplified the ValidationRule to not include being through today and the code runs fine.  Of course, hapless user can now enter invalid dates in the future...

Is there some size limitations to a table's field validation rule storage?

Comment: Must be since you got error message and reducing length resolved. Unrelated but am curious - I have never used `Strings`. Why are you? I have used Format() just fine without `Strings.` prefix.

Comment: I manually built the following Rule in form design and it does not error: `Between #5/1/2020# And #8/31/2020# Or =0 Or Is Null`. So don't see why your code fails.

Comment: Thanks for looking at this.  My use of Strings is based on an overabundance of caution.  Note there is nothing wrong with the ValidationRule expression.  It just looks like when there is a lot of them in a single table, something in the internals breaks and throws the 3309 error.  Using shorter expressions does not, so perhaps it is a space issue.  This is Access 2013 in case the more recent versions have fixed this.

Comment: I don't do formatting and setting properties like this in table. Do it on form and report. Why are you setting these properties on table with VBA on startup?

Comment: I set it in the table so it is applied in multiple form-views.  Seemed efficient and keeping the rule with the data definition seems like good design.  Can you explain why it is better to do it in the form?

Comment: Users should not interact with tables so it is not helpful to them and usually not relevant to report design. I just set these properties when I need them on forms. Still don't understand why you need to do this every time db opens.

Comment: I do this every time since the date changes.  In 1999, the ability to use a date() function inside the ValidationRule was lost.  So the rule had to be updated.

Comment: I have simplified the rule to not include the comparison with today's date and added AfterUpdate functions to every date form control to check it then.  Seems to work.  No protection when the values are changed in table view, but one needs to be careful then anyways.  Note, none of this has anything to do with Report Design.  It has to do with validating user input.

Comment: I have no problem using Date() function in Validation Rule property. Works perfectly. I know question has nothing to do with report design. I only mentioned that as further reasoning why I don't do formatting in tables.